# reuse function from other agent using lotus script

Tags: lotusscript

Can we re-use function from another agent within the same database by using lotusscript?

For example i have function getManager in "Run Report" agent and i want to use getManager in "Send email" agent in the same database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the function to a [Script Library](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/cbc2ce08be9a486c85256c54004ba66b?OpenDocument).  Then put a [Use Statement](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/fd30ce5a9e41a5f385256c54004ba682?OpenDocument) in both agents to reference the library.  Both agents will be able to use the same function.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I noted about this way. Is there any way we can share the function without moving it to script library?

Comment: No, there is no other way.  Use a script library.  That's why they exist.